# Is it OK to omit returning fields instead of null, for nullable fields in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Lets say I have a type as follows:

```
type Person {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  email: String
}
```

The email field can be `null`. Is it OK when returning a Person from resolver, to simply not return an email field on a Person object like:

```
{
  id: '1056'
  name: 'Bob Smith',
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  id: '1056'
  name: 'Bob Smith',
  email: null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can omit that property from the value returned in the parent field's resolver.

Every field in your schema has a default resolver that runs if you don't specify a resolver yourself (assuming the resolver is triggered in the first place). In your example, if we omit the resolver for `email`, the default resolver will effectively do the following:

- Look for a property called `email` on the value the parent field resolved to (in this case, the `Person` object)
- If the property is found, it will resolve to the value of the property -- if the property is a function, it will call the function first and resolve to the returned value
- If the property is not found, it will resolve to null

In other words, if a property with the same name as the field doesn't exist in the parent value, the field will always resolve to null by default. It's also worth pointing out that GraphQL does not have a concept of `undefined`, only `null`. In GraphQL.js, undefined values are always coerced to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In GraphQL you **always** return what the consumer app(frontend/query) asks for.

So, if someone queries a user like:

```
query getUser {
  user {
   id
   name
   email
  }
}
```

and if the email is null, then the output will be:

```
{
  id: '1056'
  name: 'Bob Smith',
  email: null
}
```

but, if you change the consumer query to only ask for `id` and `name`, then it wont return the email.

You can't define a resolver that only returns if not null.

Comment: Yes, but does the resolver have to return null for the email field or is omitting enough? In my testing, if a field is omitted that the client asks for that is nullable, GraphQL returns null.

Comment: @Kainan in your resolver you have to return null somehow if the email value does not exist. But if the client does not ask for it, the resolver for email will not kick-in.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this question is incorrect. As per [the spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Executing-Selection-Sets), during GraphQL execution each field is expected to have it's executed value added to the result map for the response key. If a field fails to resolve with an error, the field should be included with a `null` value. If the field executes to a `null` value, the field should be included with a `null` value. There is no valid response format in which a nullable field that is selected by the operation's selection set is allowed to be omitted.